brmultinom brglm2 vifs and dredge dont work
I am fitting a brmultinom now (instead of previous multinom), but I can not get the VIF or dredge function working on the new model. Any advise?
my code is
library(MuMIn)
options(na.action = na.fail)

dat$Sex <- as.factor(dat$Sex)
dat$season <- as.factor(dat$season)
dat$Data.origin <- as.factor(dat$Data.origin)
str(dat$Length)
str(dat$VBT)

#


model2 <- brmultinom(prey_new ~ 
                      Sex +
                      season +
                      Data.origin +
                      Length +
                      VBT,
                    data = dat,type="AS_mean",maxit=999)


where prey_new is a matrix
summary(model2)
dredge_model_multi <- dredge(model2, rank = "AICc")

and then it starts doing it (fixed term is intercept), but then gives an error
Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
Error in cf[, 2L] : subscript out of bounds
options(na.action = na.omit)
vif(model2, na.rm = T)

Error in if (names(coefficients(mod)[1]) == "(Intercept)") { :
argument is of length zero
Previously on the multinom (nnet) I coudl also run a pseudor2 which doesnt run anymore now:
library("DescTools")
# Calculate the R Square
PseudoR2(model2, which = c("CoxSnell","Nagelkerke","McFadden"))

Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “class”, “probs”
Any experiences with this/ tips on how to solve the issues?

In my experience, if the code ran in previous sessions, two things were happening: 1) I did not run the code from top to bottom, 2) package versions may have changed. The latter one can be ameliorated using i.e. renv package.

Yes, my packages (not versions) did change. I use now brmultinom of brglm2 instead of multinom of nnet. This is because of my poisson distributed data, with bias reduced options in brmultinom. I will look into renv package, but I am not familiar with it for now.

So, I fixed it by extracting the model calls through dredge with the multinom model but with evaluate=F and then looping all possible formulas with brmultinom and extracted AICc.
